# unzip or decompress data from API response in angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm using unzip function to decompress the zipped response from API in typescript (angular2).

```
customers:any=[];
zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(response), function(err, uncompressedMessage) 
{
  if(err) 
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else 
  {
    resultArray = JSON.parse(uncompressedMessage.toString());
    consloe('response After Unzip within fun',resultArray);        
    this.customers = resultArray; // error undefined
  }
});
console('response After Unzip outside fun',resultArray); // undefined
```

Here the resultArray is only accessible within function but not outside. I tried for declaring global variable and aceess it but not able access the value So, pls suggest me that how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `function(err, uncompressedMessage) {}` is asynchronous. And you are trying to access `resultArray` before it is set.

What you can do is wrap the uncompress functionality in a function that returns a `Promise` as follows:

```
let uncompress = (response) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    zlib.gunzip(Buffer.from(response), function(err, uncompressedMessage) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            let resultArray = JSON.parse(uncompressedMessage.toString());        
            resolve(resultArray);
        }
    });
});
```

Once that is done, when you receive the response, you can get the customers using:

```
const customers = await uncompress(response); // not undefined anymore
```

Note that the method which uses `await` keyword will have have to be declared `async`. If you don't want to do that, you can anyways use plain `Promise` like this:

```
uncompress(response).then(function(customers){ /* logic */ })
```

Don't forget to use `bind(this)` to callback like this

```
uncompress(response).then(function(customers){ /* logic */ }.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i used like this and that's works also but i cannot access it outside function like i want to get customers into `this._customersList`. 
 `uncompress(response).then(function(customers){ 
              console.log('customers are:',customers);                                   
               this._customersList = customers; // this is undefined 
            })  console.log('this._customersList:',this._customersList);  // undefined`

Comment: for above i'm getting error like this.        ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property '_customersList' of undefined

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks your help is really appreciated i used `bind(this)` ex:`uncompress(response).then(function(customers){ 
              this._customersList = customers; // it's working
              console.log('customers inside :',customers);
            }.bind(this)) 
            console.log('customers on ouside:',this._customersList); // not getting value`

Comment: i want to use value of this._customersList to other functions also so, how can i access value outside.